Series where father and daughter are abducted from Earth and forced to fight for an Imperium
I'm trying to find the name of a science fiction series I found on Kindle Unlimited. I started the series and read two books. However, I've been waiting so long that I've forgotten the name of the series and even the author!
The main character and his daughter are abducted by alien AI robot and forced to fight other aliens to the death. When he was abducted the AI killed his dog. Later they are purchased from the AI by other humans who are part of a mercenary group. These humans have also been abducted from Earth. The main character discovers that humans have been abducted for hundreds and hundred of years. The mercenary group is part of an Imperium which does not include Earth. The group keeps backups of each member in case of death. The main character dies and is cloned several times before being caught and sentenced to 20 years of 'death' by the Imperium for killing the Imperium citizens he was forced to fight by the AI. When he is revived, his daughter has grown up and has cloned his dog. Later he meets a very important person in the Imperium who is called "The Centurion." The Centurion was abducted from Rome while leading Roman legions. The Centurion is an enigmatic character who as altered his physiology, adding wings to himself.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?

It was quite a while back, I read every day and go through quite a few books. I don't recall exactly how long ago.

This sounds like Swarm by BV Larson.  Alien abduction, testing, fighting, centaurs... it's a pretty good, though not perfect, match.

That's the one! Thank you for this. It's been bugging me for weeks!
